# $\Pr(B\cap C \cap D~ |~ A)= \Pr(B~|~A)~ \Pr(C~|~A\cap B)~ \Pr(D~|~A\cap B\cap C)$

Tags: probability

What's the name of this rule:

$\Pr(B\cap C \cap D~ |~ A)= \Pr(B~|~A)~ \Pr(C~|~A\cap B)~ \Pr(D~|~A\cap B\cap C)$

I'm trying to find the wikipedia link about it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a consequence of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)), which states:
$$
P(A_4\cap A_3\cap A_2\cap A_1)=P(A_1)P(A_2\mid A_1)P(A_3\mid A_2\cap A_1)P(A_4\mid A_3\cap A_2\cap A_1).
$$
Relabel the events on the LHS as $D$, $C$, $B$, $A$, respectively, divide both sides by $P(A)$, and you end up with the result you're seeking.